# Dynamically add a class __dict__ property in Python

Tags: python, namedtuple

I am trying to add a `__dict__` member to classes generated by namedtuple. (`__dict__` is present in python 2.7.3, but was removed in 2.7.5. See http://bugs.python.org/issue15535. It is present and documented in python 3.3.) My code uses vars(nametuple_object), which is based on `__dict__`. I would like to patch the class when needed.

Here is what I have tried:

```py
# Applies to Python 2.7.5 +
    
C = namedtuple('C', ['x', 'y'])
if not hasattr(C, '__dict__'):
    C.__dict__ = property(C._asdict)
```

This does not work because C inherits a `__dict__`, so hasattr is always true and (when forced) the property assignment returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "namedtuple_dict.py", line 8, in <module>
    C.__dict__ = property(C._asdict)
AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

Perhaps, is there a way to refer to C members that are not inherited?

---

SOLUTION

Here is my namedtuple wrapper that uses rdb's suggestion of just inheriting from the namedtuple class rather than trying to modify it:

```py
def namedtuple_with_dict(typename, field_names, **kwargs):
    cls = namedtuple(typename, field_names, **kwargs)
    return type(typename, (cls,), {'__dict__': property(cls._asdict)})
```

Comment: Is switching from `vars` to `_fields` an option?

Comment: I had a very similar use case but my solution was to change the `__dict__` call to a `dict(zip(c._fields, c))` where c is your namedtuple instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

namedtuple sets __slots__ to an empty tuple, which is specifically to avoid creating a __dict__ for the sake of memory optimisation.  This means that it does not and cannot have __dict__ by its very design.  You cannot assign __dict__, or define any new fields for that matter when __slots__ is present.

This does not apply to derived classes, though, so you can do:

```
CBase = namedtuple('C', ['x', 'y'])

class C(CBase):
    __dict__ = property(CBase._asdict)

print C(1, 2).__dict__
```